# best way to find the index of value greater than threshold value in +ve slope

Tags: python, numpy

I have list of tuple of index value and count as below

```
count_array = [(1, 10000), (2, 15000), (3, 3000), (4, 500), (5, 600), (6, 2000), (7, 10000)]
```

And threshold value as 1000 as below

```
threshold = 1000
```

I have written a sample code which gives me index no and value greater than theshold value in +ve slope

```
def findIndex():
    index = 0
    count = 0
    for x, y in count_array:
        if y < threshold:
            index = x
    for x, y in count_array:
        if x > index:
            return x, y

print(findIndex())
```

output : (6, 2000)

Can someone help me is there any otherway to implement the logic in fastest way?

Comment: Try to post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: For your information, my answer is 3 times faster than the other, just because it's in one line it doesn't mean it's faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sort it before and after retrieve by index:

```
>>> count_array = [(1, 10000), (2, 15000), (3, 3000), (4, 500), (5, 600), (6, 2000), (7, 10000)]

>>> print(count_array[sorted(count_array, key=lambda obj: obj[1] < threshold)[-1][0]])
>>> (6, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is to optimize what you exactly wrote, you can just skip the second `for` since what you want is the next index after the first `for` loop. This should work:

```py
count_array = [(1, 10000), (2, 15000), (3, 3000), (4, 500), (5, 600), (6, 2000), (7, 10000)]
threshold = 1000


def find_index(count_array, threshold):
    index = 0
    for x, y in count_array:
        if y < threshold:
            index = x

    return count_array[index]


print(find_index(count_array, threshold))

>>> (6, 2000)
```